# How to highlight multiple characters in php, (when the characters are chinese)?

Tags: php, regex, string

please understand my problem before mark it as a duplicate, 
i know how to highlight multiple characters in a string, but it works only for English Characters, but i am looking same for the string built in chinese.
Mean to say, how to highlight the specific chinese characters from a string.

Example:
let's say if i have some specific words:

**words:** 各領域,頂尖,職涯,生涯,老生常談,陳腔濫調

and here is the content:

**string:** 但在今天的時候你要控制好自己的情緒與嘴巴，看看第二天你是否還那麼覺得。」
在今年波克夏・海瑟威公司的股東大會中，巴菲特告訴一位好奇的七年級學生說

now how to highlight the words in the given string?

Please help me to sort out this problem

Comment: Not sure there is an occurrence for one of your words in your example string.

Comment: This is the only character in the words and string list, `生`. Are you looking to match any of those words/characters?

Comment: (This question is effectively uneditable, because of the Chinese characters. It's a long-standing bug in the Stack Overflow platform, already reported to _Meta_.)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `preg_match`:

```
<?php
$str = "但在今天的時候你要控制好自己的情緒與嘴巴，看看第二天你是否還那麼覺得。」 在今年波克夏・海瑟威公司的股東大會中，巴菲特告訴一位好奇的七年級學生說";
$check = preg_match("/各領域,頂尖,職涯,生涯,老生常談,陳腔濫調/", $str);
echo $check;
?>
```